# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when apply style to class base component with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am just started to learn reactjs using material-ui but getting this error when apply style to my component. My code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));

class NavMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }
    render() {
        const classes = useStyles();
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton
                            edge="start"
                            className={classes.menuButton}
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="Menu"
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography
                            variant="h6"
                            className={classes.title}
                        >
                            News
                        </Typography>
                        <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default NavMenu;
```

and this is Error:

[image]

Comment: Use `withStyles` instead, then the `classes` come in as `props`.

Comment: it worked. thank you.
but now I cant use "marginRight: theme.spacing(2)".
Is there anyway to use makeStyles with classes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

material-ui `makeStyles` function only works inside function components, as it uses the new React Hooks APIs inside.

You have two options:

1. Convert your class component to a functional component.
2. Use a Higher Order Component [as in material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api)

I personally recommend the first approach, as this is becoming the new standard in React development.
[This tutorial may help you get started with functional components](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component/)
and [check the docs for React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: what if I need to keep state inside the object? The material-ui docs are built using this function everywhere. The other option is to convert the class stuff to plain CSS which is tedious but failsafe.

Comment: Keeping state inside a function component with `useState` is the way to go!

Answer (score 4):

Use `withStyles`:

`App.js`:

```js
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
// ...

const styles = theme => ({
    paper: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        // ...
    },
    // ...
})

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props
        // ...
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App)
```

`Root.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import App from './App'
import {ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/styles'
import theme from '../theme'

export default class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <App/>
                </ThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

`theme.js`:

```js
import {createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: ...
        secondary: ...
    },
    // ...
}

export default theme
```

<sup>See [Theming - Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/).</sup>

---

See [Higher-order component API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api).

Answer (score 3):

if you have created a functional component and still run into this issue... the next thing to look for are the dependency versions.

I tried a new [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ktnk8t) to test a material-ui component and got this error. My dependencies were:

> react 16.12
>
> react-dom 16.12
>
> @material-ui/core 4.9.14

So I had to change to latest react version using `react@latest` and `react-dom@latest` which got me to the following:

> react 16.13.1
>
> react-dom 16.13.1
>
> @material-ui/core 4.9.14

Sharing here so that it can help other people who run into this... thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647561) for the hint