# react material-ui textfield getting error: invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I have this simple code to show the text field:

I get the error

> Error in /turbo_modules/react@16.13.0/cjs/react.development.js (1465:13)
>   Invalid hook call.

The code is at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6dgvfj?file=UserForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const UserForm = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            This is userform component.
            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />

        </div>
    );
}

export default UserForm;
```

Comment: Your error log says, different version of react and react-dom. have them updated.. it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**react** and **react-dom** packages always get released in pair. So they are bound to be of same release, to work together. In your case, react was of 16.12.0 and react-dom of 16.13.0

Your package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.6",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0"
  },
```

change it to

```
    "react": "16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "16.13.0"
```

Comment: thanks.that works well.   if i try     "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0"  it doesn't work  but 6.13.0 for both works well