# I get the Error message: "Invalid hook call" when I try to run my React app. Can't understand why

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I get the error message: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component` when I try to run my react app.

```js
import React from "react";
import BarChart from "../components/BarChart";
import LineChart from "../components/LineChart";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  row: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
});

const Index = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className={classes.row}>
        <BarChart />
        <LineChart />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Index;
```

It fails in line 16 (`const classes = useStyles();`).

The Navbar, BarChart and LinChart components is just components that I have created and it doesn't seem like the code breaks in these components. I'm able to run my code without any error messages if iI remove line 16.

Any ideas what might help?

Comment: Try putting the definition inside the function body and tell if that still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you rendering `Index`?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman [Based on the docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) the usage looks correct. The definition should be outside of the component.

Comment: Check your ```package.json``` and see if all ```@material-ui``` dependecies are installed. Your code works fine with no error on my pc. I've seen this same problem with the hook here on stack, can't remeber where, but the problem was missing dependecies.

Comment: I have both `@material-ui/core`and `@material-ui/styles` in my dependencies. Do I need any more? @CevaComic

Comment: How are you calling `Index`? Is it like `<Index />` or `Index()`?

Comment: The code snippet is from my `index.js`file. That is the landing page of my React app, so I'm not calling `Index` anywhere else than what I do in the snippet in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when apply style to class base component with material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329992/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com)

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not. Do you know any other possible solution?

Answer (score -1):

I tried makeStyles locally and it worked perfectly fine. Kindly check your dependencies and update them to latest then try again.
I'm currently having:
`"react": "^16.8.2", "react-dom": "^16.8.2", "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.12"`

Comment: Thank you for this link, but I have the same version of the dependencies as the person in the Possible Solution..

Comment: Please don't answer with a link to another answer. You should flag the question as duplicate instead :)